# How to create custom source model for custom attribute type select?

Tags: magento

I tried to search this but couldn't find any. When creating a custom product attribute with select type programmatically, Magento always assigns **eav/entity_attribute_source_table** as the source model.

There are 2 issues with this default source model:

1. I can't auto populate the field with data taken programmatically from somewhere else other than have to type the data list manually one by one.
2. Although I have specified the "default" or "default_value" (I can see in the database that the value is there), the field is still showing empty as the first line.

How I can change the default source_model to my own source model for select type?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great example of this in `Mage_Customer`, installer: `mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php`

In it, a country source model is being assigned to customer address attribute `country_id`.

```
$installer->updateAttribute(
    'customer_address',
    'country_id',
    'source_model',
    'customer/entity_address_attribute_source_country'
);
```

Change this to catalog_product, your attribute, and source model.

Comment: Hmm, I thought the source_model can be assigned during the attribute creation process. It seems I have to add the updateAttribute() step for all the new attributes (because mostly the new attributes are type of select). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The key you are looking for is to pass a `source` value in your SQL setup. Make sure your `$installer` is an [EAV setup object](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup.php).

You would do the following in your setup script:

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->starSetup();

// Setup customer multiselect attribute
$attr = array(
    'backend'      => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
    'input'        => 'multiselect',
    'label'        => 'Permissions',
    'note'         => 'Used for group-based frontend permissions.',
    'required'     => false,
    'sort_order'   => '1000',
    'source'       => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table', // Change it here
    'user_defined' => true
);
$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'permissions', $attr);

// Add options for permissions
$options = array(
    'attribute_id' => $installer->getAttributeId('customer', 'permissions'),
    'value' => array(
        'place_order'    => array('Can Place Orders'),
        'view_catalog'   => array('Can View the Catalog'),
    )
);
$installer->addAttributeOption($options);

$installer->endSetup();
```

Utimately, I believe the source model can be anything that provides a `toOptionArray()` function.

Comment: There is no problem for multiselect. I can assign the source model for multiselect, but not select. Even though I've assign my own source_model, it'll still use the default one until I run the updateAttribute().

Comment: The above example should work with either. Can you update the question with your code?

Answer (score 0):

You set the source type as shown below.

```
'source'        => 'categoryattr/attribute_source_type',
```

and create the file Attribute\Source\Type.php and the create the options and set the value 0 for default option.

```
 $this->_options[] = array (
            'label' => 'Select Category',
            'value' => '0'
        );
```

please refer below for file structure and step by step explanation.

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/how-to-create-custom-attribute-source-type-in-magento/